# Do we need to create a new RenderPassDescriptor for each draw, or we can cache it and reuse it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

Do we need to create a new `RenderPassDescriptor` for each draw, or we can cache it and reuse it?

If not, what about the multisample texture and the depth stencil texture? Do I also need to recreate them on each pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some objects in **Metal** are designed to be transient and extremely lightweight, while others are more expensive and can last for a long time, perhaps for the lifetime of the app. `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` is transient object. Typically, you create a `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` object once and reuse it each time your app renders a frame.

> what about the multisample texture and the depth stencil texture? Do I
>   also need to recreate them on each pass?

`MTLTexture` type objects is not transient, reuse these objects in performance sensitive code, and avoid creating them repeatedly.

Comment: How do you reuse a MTLRenderPassDescriptor in conjunction with `CAMetalLayer`? `CAMetalLayer` spits out a new Drawable with `nextDrawable` which makes it impossible to reuse MTLRenderPassDescriptor

Comment: What exactly makes you think it's impossible?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 i do not understand, if MTLRenderPassDescriptor is transient then i need to recreate a new one on each pass no ?

Comment: @loki you can create a new `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` whenever you want. It doesn't matter in terms of performance if you create it on every single frame or create it once and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

MTLRenderPassDescriptor are generally lightweight, so creating them is not a big perf hit.
But MTLRenderEncoders in Metal are most costly operations. But in my experience what I noticed is that if you cache MTLRenderPassDescriptor with some default properties and only update properties you need to modify then we can save a lot on perf in creating encoders.